# Converting Attribute Directive to Element in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I'm trying get my head around this Attribute Directive provided in Angular 2.

Initially I thought I can create only directives using Attribute, but then when I tried few things I'm able to create directives using Elements also.

Please refer following code where I'm able to create a Element directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'myDir'
})
export class MyDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() prop1: boolean;
    @Input() prop2: boolean;
    constructor() {
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.prop1);
        console.log(this.prop2);
    }
}
```

**Can use it like below**

```
<myDir [prop2]="true">Hello World</myDir>
```

**Rendered HTML**

[image]

**Questions:**

- Why it is called Attribute directive if it is based on the selector you provide.

  *For example:*

  - if I'm providing [myDir] then I can use it as attribute
  - But if I'm using myDir as selector this will make it as element directive.

Answer (score 2):

I's called attribute directive only if you're using an attribute selector.

If you're using a class or element selector it's not an attribute directive anymore.

In general directives are just called directives.

Comment: No, id selectors are not supported.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to it...as what I understand is selectors provided in Directives or Components are CSS selectors...where we can make it element,class,attribute..then why not id(with #) as id is also a valid css selector

Comment: They are not CSS selectors. Only element, attribute, and class selectors. You also can't use selector combinators like space, `>`, or `+` (only selectors targeting exactly one element).

Comment: #myDir will also target to only one element like .myDir

Comment: I don't know the reason, but it's not supported. You can add any attribute that's unique, therefore this is not much of a limitation.

Comment: I'm upvoting it as it provided some new information but cannot accept it as answer because the quiestion is still there "why it is called as Attribute directive"

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, because it isn't called attribute directive if it doesn't use an attribute selector. The question is based on wrong assumptions.

Comment: I also don't understand what you want to convert to.

Comment: But if you see Angular doc they have mentioned that there are only three types of directives component,attribute and structural

Comment: Please provide a link. Also why do you think that contradicts anything I said?

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. It's just more common to use attribute selectors for directives. The text in the docs is misleading.